# Drawing exotic fonts in a java applet

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, applet

I'd like to draw symbols contained in exotic fonts such as Wingdings, Webdings (they are called dingbats : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat) in a java applet. When using Graphics.drawString() I end up with the typical 'square symbol' for each character in the drawn string. I could not find any answer by googling and I guess it's not something common.

In the past I've done it with C# WPF, failed to do it with SVG and HTML. Is it possible in java?

**EDIT: Solved. There was a subtlety.** Even though the symbol you want in such a font is linked to character `'a'`, it is in fact necessary to pass `"\uF061"` to g.drawString() and not `"a"`. Otherwise you end up with the square symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Even though the symbol you want in such a font is linked to character 'a', it is in fact necessary to pass "\uF061" to g.drawString() and not "a". Otherwise you end up with the square symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `Font` to a Jar (assuming you have the right to distribute it) that is on the run-time class-path of the applet.  I.E.  Add a reference to the Jar to the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.  Access it via (something like):

```
URL dingbatURL = this.getClass().getResource("/fonts/dingbat.ttf");
```

Then look to the `Font` methods for the [`createFont(int,InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) method.

```
Font dingbatFont = Font.createFont(Font.PLAIN,dingbatURL.openStream());
```

Thereafter is should be possible to use the `Font` in the `Graphics` instance.

Comment: Actually it is not a packaging problem, because I get the same problem when transforming the java applet to a JFrame. I should have mentionned that, sorry. Thank you for your answer as it has led me to the solution by looking further.