# How to draw char of Wingding.ttf font with Java Graphics.DrawString?

Tags: java, graphics, drawstring, non-unicode

I am trying to draw characters from Wingding.ttf font with Java Graphics.DrawString. But resulting image contains only rectangle instead of char.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();

Font font = new Font("Wingdings", Font.PLAIN, 20);
graphics.setFont(font);

graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

graphics.drawString("\u00d8", 10, 10); // THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD char

ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(TEST_DATA_DIR + "bullet_char.png"));
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think wingdings is one of the "standard" fonts

```
Font font = null;
try {
    font=Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
        new FileInputStream(new File("/pathto/WINGDINGS.TTF")) );
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
font=font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 200);
graphics.setFont(font);
```

once you load the font (its always PLANE 1 pnt) you can the derive the style and size you want....

Answer (score 0):

As similar questions has been answered here: [Drawing exotic fonts in a java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692095/drawing-exotic-fonts-in-a-java-applet), you need to pass `\uF0d8` instead of `\u00d8`.

```
graphics.drawString("\uF0d8", 10, 10);
```